# AngularJS - Select dynamic ng-repeat DOM element in directive

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

**Problem:**
I have a directive which has a list `<ul>` and dynamically generated list items `<li>`s. I want to change the css of one of these `<li>` items.

Here's the code the for the `template` attribute of the directive:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-class="{selected: (color===selected) }" ng-click="pick(color)" style="background-color:{{color}};"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to change the css of the **third element**, that is `$first + 2`, but I don't know how to access it.

**What I've tried**
1) Since I want the directive to work without jQuery I've been trying with `angular.element` (which is jqLite). I can access the `<ul>` by `angular.element.find('li')` or just `element.children()` inside the `link` of the directive but I can't seem to get "further down" than that, because they are dynamically created (I guess).

2) I've been trying to access it through `$first+2` and adding a css class to it in the `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ... ng-class="{ ... , cssClass: ($first+2) }" ...></li>
</ul>
```

But then all `<li>` elements are affected.

[Here's a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Go67UgVPw5dyUywmkWEW?p=preview)

Comment: can check for `$index == 2`

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, it solved my problem. Post as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use `$index`

```
<li ng-class="{ cssClass: $index == 2 }"></li>
```